# Validate inputs on server side

Tags: apex, validation, bestpractice, form

### BACKGROUND

I am working on a lightning component which is a simple form that takes from, to emails and a message body as user input and passes this data to an apex controller.

[image]

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class MessageController
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void send(String toEmail, String fromEmail, String messageBody)
    {

        // create a single email message
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage myEmail = new SingleEmailMessage();
        // populate myEmail with data
        // .... skipped for brevity

        try 
        {
            SendService.send(myEmail); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Message send error: ' + ex.getMessage());    
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a custom `SendService` which provides messaging services and performs other logic before actual sending. This service will be reused in multiple places.

### QUESTION

Where should I validate input data, namely these values `(String toEmail, String fromEmail, String messageBody)` and what validations do I need?

Everything that comes from UI is not secure and needs to be validated and sanitized. **My question is when/where and how?**

> when/where

1. Logically validation of the `fromEmail` parameter can be performed right in the `send` method of the apex controller. But this approach introduces code duplication. If I create another apex class `SendSeveral.cls` that would allow to send several messages to a list of records, it might have this method `public static void send(List<String> recipientIds, String fromEmail, String messageBody)`.

This tells that we can move validation to the `SendService` level. But in case of `SendSeveral.cls` it might be wise to stop the execution if `fromEmail` is null and not even go further to `SendService`

> how

2. This actually leads to the **how** part. Maybe it is reasonable to perform basic checks for input (not blank, null, empty) directly in the controller. And if everything looks good, proceed to `SendService` which in turn performs domain logic checks: `fromEmail` is actually of the email address type, etc.

Does anybody know best practices of input validation?

this is what I've found so far:

1. [Validate a form with Apex and server side controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245638/validate-a-form-with-apex-and-server-side-controller)
2. [Where should data validation occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819678/where-should-data-validation-occur)

Comment: [¯\_(ツ)_/¯](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/VagueNearAyeaye-small.gif)

Comment: @MartinLezer, that's why I am asking this question. What is the best practice? Having checks in both places, fine. Is there a pattern for this kind of logic. I believe there should be.

Comment: Validating emails is a fool's errand. Even if you do manage to validate the format (not as trivial a task as you might think), the "valid" email may not correspond to any inbox.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I couldn't agree more with you regarding emails validation. My question, however, is about general approach towards validating inputs from UI on the server. I gave emails just for example, it could be any other user-provider fields. How and where should a developer validate and sanitize data that comes from UI? Should it first check that required inputs are not null in the controller, and perform business logic checks in the deeper layers of the application?